# iOS 7 UITextView select behaviour

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios7

In 6.x it used to work fine.

Starting with 7.x, all my apps UITextView controls when you click on a line, the cursor is positioned at the start of that line. But I click on the right side of the line, so it should go to the end of that line, not to the start.

But in all other apps, including e-mail, it works fine.
It also worked fine in iOS 6.

Do I miss something?

Comment: I get exactly the same thing.  Touch at end of line - selects the beginning of the line.  Also, if you have a few blank lines in a row, trying to put the cursor on the middle one often results in a missing cursor.  Can't figure out what I have done to trigger it.

Comment: I get exactly the same behaviour building the Apple sample "Keyboard Accessory". On the Apple Developer Forums in a thread entitled "UITextView bugs even as GM is seeded" (https://devforums.apple.com/message/889840#889840), the code from user 'yamagame' on Sep 15th seems to fix it for me.